# Setting Character from array made from string as an Int?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a textfield of user input which will be a string of 2 Int's

I take them and make an array of characters.

I then want to set each of those characters to Int properties.

My code is this but it doesnt work:

```
    func robotStartingPositionSet() {
    let robotStart = self.robotStartPosition.text!
    let coords = Array(robotStart.characters)
    self.usersRobot.xPosition = Int(coords[0])
    self.usersRobot.yPosition = Int(coords[1])
}
```

Any idea how I can get the characters at those index paths to set as Int to the properties?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can separate your two numbers by a comma and use this: let array = string.components(separatedBy: ",")

Comment: that could work but then how do i force a comma to the user and also i still have to set the array values, so really thats no different an approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
self.usersRobot.xPosition = Int(String(coords[0]))
```

Another possible solution is to separate numbers by a comma and the following code would be like this:

```
let coords = robotStart.components(separatedBy: ",")
```